# when we click on the button block the execution of the second function if the first function displays alert_box otherwise execute it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which executes two functions, the first function checks the dates entered by the user and the second function makes an ajax call to load a url.
in my code when I click on the button both functions run.
I would like if the first function displays a warning message on a date error entered in the field, the code will not execute the second otherwise it directly executes the second function.

Button:

```
<button type="button" class="" onclick="javascript:
        date_control($('#{$dateSId}').val(),$('#{$dateFId}').val());
        call_Js($('#{$dateSId}').val(),$('#{$dateFId}').val());">search by date 

</button>
```

First function:

```
function date_control(beginTs,endTs){

if ((beginTs.length && endTs.length) != 0) {
    var tabDeb = beginTs.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)$/);
    var tabFin = endTs.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)$/);
    beginDate = new Date(tabDeb[3], tabDeb[2] - 1, tabDeb[1], tabDeb[4], tabDeb[5]);
    endDate = new Date(tabFin[3], tabFin[2] - 1, tabFin[1], tabFin[4], tabFin[5]);
    if (beginDate > endDate) {
        show_alertbox('Start date is greater than the end date');
        return;
    }
} else {
    show_alertbox('One of the two dates is empty please enter the start and end date');
    return;
 }
```

}

Comment: Can you not move the call to the second function to within the first function?

Comment: As an aside, don't use inline event handlers like `onclick`. They are not good practice, and lead to very messy and hard to maintain HTML - as you've now seen. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead; either jQuery's `on()` method or the native `addEventListener()`

Comment: Consider using an event handler rather than `onclick=` as it will be easier to maintain.  Your first function ideally needs to return true/false so the calling code knows whether to continue.  You *could* check if the div for `show_alertbox` is visible (an alert is shown) or use the alertbox api to determine this (if there is one) but a simple `return true;` `if (date_control(...) === false) call_js` (or whichever way round you prefer: true = continue / true = alert show (so don't continue))

Comment: @freedomn-m  how to use event handler in this case knowing that I have to do on the button without changing the syntax?

Comment: *have to do on the button without changing the syntax* - makes no sense.  You're asking how to fix something but saying **you can't change anything**.    Already shown you how to change your onclick= as long as you return a value.  As above `onclick="javascript: if (date_control(...) === false) call_js(..)"`

Comment: sorry i mean in button no syntax

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you're using the inline onclick (should use an event handler), changing the first function to:

```
function date_control(beginTs,endTs){
    if ((beginTs.length && endTs.length) != 0) {
        var tabDeb = beginTs.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)$/);
        var tabFin = endTs.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)$/);
        beginDate = new Date(tabDeb[3], tabDeb[2] - 1, tabDeb[1], tabDeb[4], tabDeb[5]);
        endDate = new Date(tabFin[3], tabFin[2] - 1, tabFin[1], tabFin[4], tabFin[5]);
        if (beginDate > endDate) {
            show_alertbox('Start date is greater than the end date');
            return;
        }
        else {
            call_Js(beginTs, endTs);
        }
    }
    else {
        show_alertbox('Please enter the start and end date');
        return;
    }
}
```

And the button to:

```
<button type="button" class="" onclick="javascript:
        date_control($('#{$dateSId}').val(),$('#{$dateFId}').val());">search by date 
</button>
```

Should solve your issue.

Comment: in the project i use the same calendar in several buttons which have different second function so it can work if only i have one button

Comment: @messoaudRostane in that case, you'll want to use an event handler, not the inline onclick event - using an event handler you can check which button was clicked.